# Liquid mercury, relativistic effects and Fermi velocity

Tags: special-relativity, solid-state-physics, fermi-energy

Reading [this news article](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/the-curious-wavefunction/what-does-mercury-being-liquid-at-room-temperature-have-to-do-with-einsteins-theory-of-relativity/)  and some related references,  I learned  that mercury’s liquidity is due to relativistic effects in Hg, where "the electron approaches about 58% of the speed of light." I do not see how this can be reconciled with [the Fermi velocity of Hg](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/fermi.html) being $1.58 \times 10^6$ m/s, almost the same as Cu $1.57 \times 10^6$ m/s and in the same order of magnitude of virtually all other metals, making relativistic corrections barely significant. The relevant [scientific article](https://moodle2.units.it/pluginfile.php/265421/mod_resource/content/1/liquid%20Hg%20Calvo_et_al-2013-Angewandte_Chemie_International_Edition.pdf) relies on numerical calculations and arguments which I am unable to relate to basic solid-state physics concepts (cf. [this](https://antoine.frostburg.edu/chem/senese/101/periodic/faq/why-is-mercury-liquid.shtml) too). My question is: how do electrons with relativistic velocities (e.g. 0.58c as above) relate to the Fermi velocity of a metal?

PS I am aware that the articles cited above are chemistry publications, but I assume that an electron's velocity should be the same in physics, possibly modulus some convention that I am not aware of.

Comment: @PM2Ring - no, they are not. See, for example, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/why-is-gold-golden/16634#16634.

Comment: @JonCuster Interesting...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it is stated in the Scientific American paper you cited,

> for the **1s electron** of mercury (atomic number 80) this effect becomes significant; the electron approaches about 58% of the speed of light, ...

(Bold is mine).
As you see the most important relativistic effects have to do with the innermost orbital, whose energy is much lower than the energy of the valence states (and of the Fermi level). There is no point to compare them. Actually, what is reported in the paper, is that the presence of strong relativistic effects on the $1s$ state has some indirect consequence on all the higher energy orbitals, up to the valence states, even if these states do not show direct relativistic effects.

A final comment on your concern about the fact that the original research was published in a chemistry journal. It is not an issue. This kind of research is interdisciplinary and many of the computational techniques used in the field were introduced by physicists. I know many physicists working on related topics. Therefore your question is completely in-topic here.

A side remark about the language used in the Scientific American paper is in order. First of all, one should not take literally the word *velocity* with quantum particles. As it is well known, velocity is not directly appearing in the Schrödinger or Dirac equations. Moreover, the paper uses the obsolete concept of relativistic mass which is fading in the physics literature. However, this is an issue with the words. The equations are the real basis of the calculations.

Comment: The SA article’s use of “relativistic mass” is interesting. I think it says that computing the Bohr radius is one of the cases where just putting $m\to \gamma m$ takes care of all the relativistic corrections. There are certainly good reasons to prefer the modern perspective, where mass is an invariant; but there were pluses to the obsolete idea of relativistic mass, too, and it’s useful to know what they were.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You write: " ... the most important relativistic effects have to do with the innermost orbital, whose energy is much lower than the energy of the valence states (and of the Fermi level)." The point of my question is  precisely this. It should be lower, but a velocity of 0.58c is much bigger than the Fermi velocity. How can that be?

Comment: @rob I agree. I see the good conceptual reasons against the "relativistic mass", but I also think that there are cases where $m \rightarrow \gamma m$ provides a useful shortcut for the final result. This is one of those cases.

Comment: @AndreaAlciato we are speaking of an electron interacting with a nucleus. Energy is not only kinetic energy. Actually, for Coulomb interaction, the lower is the potential energy, the higher the kinetic energy. The absolute value of the potential energy being higher than the kinetic energy results in negative total energy, and this value decreases when the kinetic energy increases.

Comment: @GiorgioP OK, thanks.